Crustal magnetic field of the Earth
Where can I find an accurate map of the Earth's crustal magnetic field?

what is wrong with nasa's?

start by searching for magnetogram and you will find what you are looking for,nasa and esa has good maps and so has usgs and other geological surveys in every country on our planet.

Thank you! That was very good advice.

This very much depends on what you mean by "accurate"! Two options for a consistent, globally gridded, map of crustal magnetic field scalar anomalies are the World Digital Magnetic Anomaly Map and Earth Magnetic Anomaly Grid.
The difference between these two maps is in how they decide to combine individual surveys to create the global grid, and what they do to fill in the gaps.
If you want higher resolution maps of certain areas, then you can find the individual surveys that were combined to produce these two global grids by looking at the description and reference info for each.
If by "crustal field map" you mean anything other than the scalar magnitude of the crustal field anomaly, then you need a magnetic field vector model, and that's another question...
